# Regex Matching the submatch not having some words

Tags: regex, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I want to write RewriteRule some part of URL should not end with specific set of words.

URL's like:

```
/en/drivers/drivername/play
```

But I want (drivername) section not "ending with specific words, such as "excluded" or "banned"

In other words I want following URL's to work:

```
/en/drivers/drivername/play
```

But following not to work:

```
/en/drivers/drivername-excluded/play
/en/drivers/drivername-banned/play
```

But this should be working:

```
/en/drivers/driver-excluded-name/play
/en/drivers/driver-banned-test/play
```

Is it even possible?

Without exclusion part I was using:

```
 ^(en|de)/([^\/]+)/(play|test)?
```

Comment: Why do you have iis as a tag? Are you using apache/.htaccess or what?

Comment: I use both IIS RewriteURL 2.0 extension and also HeliconApe for .htaccess whichever syntax / solution works on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, using a negative lookahead:

```
(en|de)\/([^\/]+)\/driver.+-(?!(excluded|banned)\/).*?\/(play|test)?
```

I took your regular expression and inserted the bit dealing with "drivername"

```
driver.+-(?!(excluded|banned)\/).*?
```

In this case, `(?!(excluded|banned)\/)` ensures that the "driver" section between forward slashes does not end with "excluded" or "banned" directly before the following forward slash.

https://regex101.com/r/pC8sP3/3

This appears to be working with your provided examples.

Comment: I think this does not cover  anything that has - in it (like)
    /en/driver-name-excluded/play which covers me for now, thank you